# what is the best way to navigate from one jsp page to another using JSP tags?

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have an index.jsp
I want to provide multiple links on this page to other JSP pages.
Under Web Content, I have a folder JSPViews which contains all the jsp pages whose link I want to provide on the index.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could indeed use `<a href>` tags,

And as you said you have them in the same folder you dont need to worry about directory listings,

just use like below,

```
<a href="b.jsp">b</a>
<a href="c.jsp">c</a>
```

If you need to navigate through a servlet , then you could use something like this ,

```
<a href="TestServlet?paramName="test">TestServletLink</a>
```

**NOTE : paramName indicates the parameter you are passing to the servlet .**

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Do we have any JSP syntax, I guess what you have posted is HTML?

Comment: @user3073182 there is nothing specfic as `JSP` syntax . you will use the same thing in jsp too.